# write in file is not complete without quitting the IDLE(Python GUI)

Tags: python, file, python-idle

I want to write something in a file.
for example,

```
fo=open('C:\\Python\\readline_test.txt','a')
for i in range(3):
 st='abc'+'\n'
 fo.write(st)
fo.close
```

then I open this python file in IDLE, and click "Run Module".
There is no error message but I find the writing is not complete if I didn't quit IDLE.
How can I complete the file writing without quitting the IDLE?
Thanks.

(I use Python 2.6.2 on Windows XP.)

Comment: `fo.close` returns the function object, as in the `a = fo.close` assignment. If you want to actually call it you need the parentheses: `fo.close()`, or, equivalently, `a()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using

```
fo.flush()
```

and mayby

```
os.fsync()
```

after writing to file object to ensure that all file operations are flushed to disk.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe a typo, but it should be:

```
fo.close()
```

Then it should work.

Alternative you can use the [`with`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement syntax ([better example](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects)):

```
with open('C:\\Python\\readline_test.txt','a') as fo:
    for i in range(3):
        fo.write('abc'+'\n')
```

The file is automatically closed when leaving the `with` block.

*(Instead of `'abc'+'\n'`, just write `'abc\n'`)*